# ElasticSearch Function Score Query not defaulting to 1 if missing field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a function score in ElasticSearch that (after other filters) gives a higher score to those customers who bought a product recently. For this I have a field "lastPurchaseOn".

The query also needs to return customers who did not buy any product, so I cannot filter on the lastPurchaseOn field being present.

```
"functions": [
    {
        "exp": {
            "lastPurchaseOn": {
                "scale": "3d"
            }
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

The problem is that when the field "lastPurchaseOn" is missing, the function returns score 1, when I would really want it to return 0.

Is there a way to make the function return 0 for missing values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_what_if_a_field_is_missing) states it pretty clearly:

> If the numeric field is missing in the document, the function will return 1.

The main reason is that there's no way for the [exponential function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_supported_decay_functions) that is being used to return 0. You can try to use a `linear`function instead of `exp`.

Comment: I did read the documentation. That's why I asked whether there was any option so 0 is returned on missing values. Changing it to linear wouldn't change the fact that 1 is returned :(

Comment: The linear function does reach 0 under certain conditions, which is not the case with `exp` or `gauss` which are both exponential functions which never reach 0. have you tried?

Comment: Did you get the chance to try it out?

Comment: Hi Val, I found they have a workaround in Github, so that's what I used: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18892

Thanks